# necesito retornar un arreglo de objetos pero mi codigo solo retorna el ultimo valor de los arreglos

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy programando un código que me esta retornando el ultimo valor de cada objeto que almaceno y lo que quiero es que me retorne todos los objetos en ese arreglo. Alguna corrección ?

```
var names = ["messi","west","tom","harry"];
var types = ["perro","gato","paloma","cuy"];
var breeds = ["chiguagua","rallado","raviche","montero"];

function createAnimalObjects(names, types, breeds) {

var animal = new Animal(names, types, breeds);
var animalsArray = [];
var arrayReference = names;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayReference.length; i++) {
    animal.name = names[i];
    animal.type = types[i];
    animal.breed = breeds[i];

    animalsArray.push(animal);
}
return animalsArray;
}
createAnimalObjects(names, types, breeds);
// for test 
function Animal (name, type, breed) {
this.name = name;
 this.type = type;
 this.breed = breed;
}
```

Comment: revisa mi respuesta, creo haberle dado solución a tu problema

Comment: Buenas, estás teniendo un problema de puntero, estás metiendo la misma instancia de animal en el array y a esa instancia estás machacando los atributos por lo que te coge la última modificación, una solución seria meter el var animal... dentro del for o como han respondido en el mismo push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cuando realices el `push()` para **animalsArray** en ese momento, crea el nuevo animal:

```
var names = ["messi","west","tom","harry"];
var types = ["perro","gato","paloma","cuy"];
var breeds = ["chiguagua","rallado","raviche","montero"];

function createAnimalObjects(names, types, breeds) {

   var animal = new Animal(names, types, breeds);
   var animalsArray = [];
   var arrayReference = names;
   for (var i = 0; i < arrayReference.length; i++) {
      animalsArray.push(new Animal(names[i],types[i],breeds[i]));
      //así ahorras código y evitas el error que te esta dando
    }
  return animalsArray;
  }
 createAnimalObjects(names, types, breeds);
// for test 
function Animal (name, type, breed) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.breed = breed;
 }
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta Travv, ahora todo va ok. Gracias

Comment: De nada, aquí estamos para ayudar.